# Export ALL list items to xml and be able to Save as a File

Tags: export, xml

Currently the customer I'm working with is using software that exports items (not SharePoint) to xml and also have the ability to save the item(s) to their local machine. The client wants to move to SharePoint and have the same feature.

I have a test SharePoint list with 2 test item. This list has 4 columns: Title, Colors, Property and Taxes. My users have no access to the server as well.

**The requirements**:

1. Grant the ability (maybe a button in the ribbon?) for users to
   export **ALL** items in a specific xml format/order (using my test
   list) shown below:

[image]

2. Grant users the ability to save the above as .xml file locally.

The xml image above is from the software the client is currently using. I modified fields to match the SharePoint columns I stated and due to sensitive data.

As one can see, the output is displaying 2 items in the order of Colors, Property, Title and Taxes.

I have looked at an article below and wondering if this is as best as it can get?:

- https://discoveringsharepoint.wordpress.com/2014/09/11/export-sharepoint-list-data-to-xml-directly-from-the-gui/

I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have custom xml format as is in your image reference(by current software) you only have one option. Write custom code to query all items in list, loop through and create required format of XML String and create new window document in javscript and pass XML string to it. it will open xml in new windows which user can save. below is code snippet opening XML in new window

```
var xmlWindow = window.open("", "");
xmlWindow.document.write(yourXmlString);
```

Else you can use Rest API and get respone in form of XML but this XML will be not user friendly readable as you will find internal nodes names, plus some other extra nodes also which might confuse end user...

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `custom solution/workflow` that generates an `XML document` based on data pulled from a `CAML query` or by directly accessing the list.

This would give you the behavior you are looking for where the users click a button and an XML file is generated for them.